# Queue work for worker threads without generating garbage

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have a method that I wish to execute on a separate thread from the main thread. It may complete and be started again at some point many times. I want to avoid generating any garbage when I want the method to run on a thread. Additionally keeping the method alive always by busy spinning is not desirable.

When using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run` this will create a new Task object that cannot be reused, thus garbage is generated. When using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` a `System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext` object is created, thus garbage is generated. Is there any way to avoid generating garbage while also avoiding keeping the method alive when it is not needed to run?

By generating garbage I mean allocating an object on the heap every time and losing the reference to the old one so it thus becomes garbage.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'no garbage'? No heap memory allocation?

Comment: The cost of "garbage" may be much less than you imagine.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid garbage?

Comment: My application may require executing this many times per second. It is real-time so stopping to do garbage collection is unacceptable and even if somehow subdued is a needless load on the system (in my case) that I have easily avoided so far

Comment: Can u use a [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) instead of a busy spin to keep the thread alive?

Comment: @John - You need to show us your code for us to help with this.

Comment: Yes, using Wait and Release on a SemaphoreSlim to make the thread "wait" for new work might do the trick